# gcc заставляет использовать 11 стандарт?

Tags: c++, c++98

В `gcc` возникает странная ошибка, когда пытаюсь скомпилировать этот код. В `clang` такого нет. В чём проблема?

> #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or
>   -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

```
#include <random> 

int main() {
    int x; //Почему тут ошибка??/
    x = 0x42; // <--
}
```

Comment: Комменты пробовали убирать? Там с триграфами история интересная получается.

Comment: Ни `gcc`, ни даже `g++` не выдают у меня такой ошибки. Как вы компилируете?

Comment: скорее всего автор вопроса забыл список include показать. А там вполне может быть что то новенькое.

Comment: @älёxölüt действительно, без комментов компилируется

Comment: У меня даже с комментами компилируется (на триграфы ругается, но варнингом)

Comment: Какую версию gcc используете?

Comment: @älёxölüt 8.2.1+20180831

Comment: На доступной в онлайне ближайшей 8.2.0 только лишь [предупреждения](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vQDWhZcWmBBVn0XS).

Comment: @älёxölüt @KoVadim посмотрел инклюды - действительно `<random>` подключен, если убрать - то нет ошибки, а только предупреждение

Comment: почему так?????

Comment: Так `<random>` это из c++11, потому и требует :)

Comment: А вот почему clang допускает даже при c++03 ключе - это хороший вопрос.

Answer (score 4):

В коде используется заголовочный файл [`<random>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/), характерный для стандарта c++11 и выше, потому и наблюдается упомянутая ошибка. Дополнительно в коде имеются приколы с триграфами (которые, кстати, в с++17 [уже запретили](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17#%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%8B)), может это тоже косвенно дало причину думать, что ошибка не там, где она действительно есть.

По поводу того, на каком основании *clang* собирает код с `<random>` при режиме `-std=c++98` задал вопрос на enSO [Enforcing C++98/03 for clang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53412721). В комментариях люди выражают уверенность, что это баг *clang*.